# How can I map between types of Event to runnable?

Tags: java

Suppose I have an interface defined as:

```
interface IEvent
{

}
```

and multiple classes implementing that event:

```
class Event1 implements IEvent {} , class Event2 implements IEvent {} ....
```

How can I create a map between the event types and a runnable object?
And How can I define a method that accepts an event type and a runnable object and adds the pair to the map?
I tried:

```
Map<T extends IEvent,Runnable> map;
void addToMap(Class<T implements IEvent> eventType , Runnable runnable) { }
```

But that didn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Class<? extends IEvent>, Runnable> map;

void addToMap(Class<? extends IEvent> eventType , Runnable runnable) {
  map.put(eventType, runnable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Class<? extends IEventType>, Runnable> map = new HashMap<>();

void addToMap(Class<? extends IEventType> eventType , Runnable runnable) {
    ...
}

...

addToMap(Event1.class, someRunnable);
addToMap(Event2.class, someOtherRunnable);
```